# Font installed, compiles to dvi, but fails compiling to pdf. "font at 600 not found"

Tags: fonts

After having answered [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/how-do-i-generate-creative-commons-license-information/8760#8760) I thought "hmm, maybe I should actually install that package and see if it's as good as it looks...

So I tried. I downloaded `ccicons.tds.zip` from [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/fonts/) and unzipped it into my `~/texmf`

this is a procedure that has worked for me before with siunitx and a couple of other packages, so I thought there'd be no problems here.

But when I try and use the package, I got an error. So I went and had a look at the readme, and it told me to run `updmap --enable Map ccicons.map` so I did. But I still get an error:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 cciconsmktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ccicons.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ccicons): Font ccicons at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

LaTeX exited abnormally with code 70 at Thu Jan 13 17:39:09
```

I don't know how to fix this.

If I compile to DVI rather than straight to PDF (that is, if I use auctex's LaTeX mode rather than the PDFLaTeX mode) I can compile the document, but the `\ccLogo` appears as a capital gamma... Also, when I compile to pdf, it says `LaTeX successfully formatted [0] pages` but the log file contains the error above.

I'm on Ubuntu 10.10 using the package manager version of TeXlive.

I have similar issues with certain of the TeX gyre fonts installed through the package manager: `tgpagella` and `tgtermes` for instance. I get more or less the same behaviour: compiles 0 pages in PDFLaTeX mode, logs an error about font not found (again mentioning "at 600" whatever that means), but I can compile to dvi fine...

I've run just about every version of `updmap` I can imagine, and since the issue also occurs with fonts installed through the ubuntu package manager, I don't think the issue has to do with that.

Complete log available [here](https://gist.github.com/793234) (with listfiles)

Comment: Related: [What is the Right Way to install a new font locally?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7632/1235)

Comment: @Hendrik Thanks, but as far as I can tell, I do have the fonts in the right place... (either that, or there is something subtly wrong with the ccicons.tds.zip on CTAN...)

Comment: It's a pity that it didn't help, but from the beginning I wasn't sure at all, so I wrote "Related".

Comment: I don't have much idea about fonts, but TeXLive knows and seems to be able to install `ccicons` from its package manager. (Actually, it was already installed on my system.) Have you tried to use `tlmgr` to do the install?

Comment: @Juan The Ubuntu version of TeXlive doesn't have tlmgr, I don't think. It's weird...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

run

```
updmap-sys --enable Map=ccicons.map
```

to make the font known to your system. If your TeX distribution was installed as root, then use `sudo`. If you had it run before always as `updmap` (without -sys) then you only have a local `pdftex.map` in your home directory. You shouldn't mix `updmap` and `updmap-sys` runs, when you are a user *and* administrator on the computer. In this case use always `updmap-sys` or `sudo updmap-sys`. It may be nessesary that you have to delete the local copy of `pdftex.map` if you are in trouble.

my testdoc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ccicons}

\begin{document}

\ccLogo
\ccAttribution
\ccShareAlike
\ccNoDerivatives

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Herbert I did this and I get the same error.

Comment: @Seamus: can you run my test doc please

Comment: @Herbert same error.

Comment: @Seamus: if you run `updmap-sys --edit` Is the `ccicons.map` listed?

Comment: @Herbert `updmap.cfg` does include a line `ccicons.map`

Comment: @Seamus: and you are sure that the fonts are saved in the write place? `~/texmf/fonts/...` if yes, then I am lost here without a direct connection to your computer ...

Comment: @Seamus, please provide the complete logfile

Comment: @Herbert see edited question

Comment: @Seamus: can you delete or rename the file `/home/seamus/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` to something else and then running `sudo updmap-sys` and look into the pdftex.map if ccicons is listed (in the new generated file in `.../texmf-var/` Not the one in your home dir

Comment: @Herbert I did this and the `/var/lib/texmf/fonts...` version of pdftex.map that updmap created does have a ccicons line.

Comment: (And ccicons now works as does tgpagella...)

Comment: @Seamus: it is a known problem that TeX gets confused when updmap runs are mixed with udpmap-sys runs.

Comment: @Herbert Ah OK. Could you update your answer proper to include some explanation for other people who might find themselves in this situation?

Comment: @Seamus: done. However, you should controll if your local installed fonts are still present. Maybe that you need another  `updmap-sys --enable Map=..` if one is now missing which was previously installed with `updmap`, if there are any.

Comment: @Herbert thanks! I think this was the only locally installed font, so untill I run into a problem I will carry on as I am!

Comment: I don't manage to apply this on El Capitan, is there any changes ? trying to use bbm font.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7, running MiKTeX 2.9, I just updated the fonts, by running (as an Admin), the "Update" module (under the "Maintenance (Admin)" folder), and then selecting all possible updates.