# MiKTeX: "Font ccicons at 600 not found"

Tags: fonts, miktex, texniccenter

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXnicCenter 1.0-RC1 (Windows 7) and try to compile the following minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ccicons}
\begin{document}
 \ccbysa
\end{document}
```

I installed the `ccicons`-package using the MiKTeX Package Manager (MPM). TeXnicCenter gives 0 errors, 0 warnings - nothing, but doesn't even create any PDF output. Reading the log-file shows the following fatal error:

> !pdfTeX error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe (file 
>       ccicons): Font ccicons at 600 not found
>       ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

While browsing the net for this error, I came across this question: [Font installed, compiles to dvi, but fails compiling to pdf. "font at 600 not found"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8899/font-installed-compiles-to-dvi-but-fails-compiling-to-pdf-font-at-600-not-fo) - which is quite the same problem that I have.

The suggested solution is to run `updmap-sys --enable Map=ccicons.map` or `updmap --enable Map=ccicons.map` but this is obviously linux command line notation. Running this from a Windows command prompt I will always get the following message:

> mkfntmap: --enable: unknown option

I also tried `-enable` or `/enable` but still the same result. So, my question, what is the correct command for Windows users? (It's quite strange as MiKTeX is originally designed for Windows, isn't it?)

The [`ccicons` readme](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ccicons) also suggests running `updmap --enable Map ccicons.map` ... Any ideas?

Comment: There's some seriously weird stuff going on here. Can someone explain what all this mapping is about and why I can't just install the font package and compile happily everafter? This doesn't seem to be too rare a problem, after all...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Without any hope of success ;-) You can try the following steps.

1. Edit the map configuration file `updmap.cfg`.  In a Command
   Prompt window, run:

   ```
   initexmf --edit-config-file updmap
   ```

   You'll want to edit this in a text editor such as Notepad.  If the
   file or any of the leading directories do not exist, create them.
2. Add this one line to `updmap.cfg` and save it:

   ```
   Map ccicons.map
   ```
3. Back at the command prompt, run:

   ```
   initexmf --mkmaps
   ```

   (Ignore any error messages.)

<sub>These steps were described as I bought the font Lucida</sub>

Comment: Will do as soon as I have 15 reputation! :)

Comment: For everyone coming here for the same problem with tgpagella: Using `Map rm-qplr.map` instead solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 8):

The message means that the map-file has not been activated correctly. Normally this happens because

- The miktex package is defective. In this case must add it manually as described by Marco.

Or

- You have a multiuser installation, but a local pdftex.map. In this case you must call `updmap` everytime you installed a font to update this local pdftex.map.

In this case the miktex package is defective. I have made a bug report.

Comment: Hi Ulrike, indeed, Marco's answer helped me to fix this. If you filed a bug report, do you mind sharing the link to the issue? I'm interested to follow this. Thanks.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3522545&group_id=10783&atid=110783

Answer (score 2):

On latest version of MikTeX, it is possible to force update of the font map files and font map database.
You open the console and two actions are available in `Task` menu:
 - Refresh file name database
 - Refresh font map files

This solved the issue on my side (`Font umvs at 600 not found`)

Comment: I had the error (Windows-MiKTeX): “Font xxxx... not found” (I don´t remember the font) and effectivelly, I´ve open the console and in Task menu I´ve apply the options "Refresh file name database" and "Refresh font map files" and it work out.

Comment: Thank-you! Just needed the `refresh font map files` action.