# How to type the symbol of viscous stress tensor?

Tags: math-mode

How to insert the symbols shown below in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character?s=1|50.3531) how to look up symbols. Once you have found the first one, it will be easy to add the subscripts and superscripts.

Comment: Can you point to a source for the symbol? Is it universally used in your field?

Comment: This symbol is used in Two-phase flow field and this is a symbol on Ishii's book.

Comment: I have never seen this symbol for the viscous stress tensor. It's is usually just an `S`

Comment: This symbol seems like some mad font scientist was melting `\mathscr` and `\mathfrac` together by accident :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this close enough?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{graphics}
\newcommand{\StressTensor}{\rotatebox{-10}{\textgoth{T}}}
\begin{document}
$\textgoth{T}$ $\textgoth{T}^D$ $\textgoth{T}_{f}^{BI}$

$\StressTensor$  $\StressTensor^D$ $\StressTensor\!_{f}^{\,BI}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Just in case you want it even closer to your picture.

Comment: Thx so much, I think this is good enough.

Comment: When I try this, 'Font ygoth at 600 not found' error occured

Comment: @LongcongWang Which TeX installation are you working with? Does [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53809/121799) help?

Comment: I use TeXworks with MiKTex

Comment: @LongcongWang Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53809/121799) help? (Of course, you need to replace `ccicons` by `yfonts`.) And you may ask a separate question because some others know this stuff much better than me and can give you more competent advice.

Answer (score 0):

Another try is the `Dobkin Script` font (available [here](https://www.fontzillion.com/fonts/dieter-steffmann/dobkin-script?utm_source=fontsquirrel.com&utm_medium=matcherator_link&utm_campaign=dobkinscript) for instance as `.ttf` - hence the example below needs to be compiled with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX):

[image: example_output]

```
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
  \newfontfamily{\dobscr}{Dobkin Script}
  \DeclareTextFontCommand{\textscr}{\dobscr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
  \DeclareMathOperator{\stresstensor}{\textscr{T}\kern2pt}

\begin{document}
\(\stresstensor\)

\(\stresstensor^D\)

\(\stresstensor_f^{BI}\)
\end{document}
```