# How do I set the \skewchar of a math font?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4192/bad-positioning-of-math-accents-for-the-beamer-standard-font/7576#7576), I set the `\skewchar` of a font, but I think I don't do it in the right way. The problem is that it's a math font, and those seem to get initialized only when they are used, namely when the first `$`, `\(` etc. occurs. (Is this correct?) So for example, just putting

```
\skewchar\csname OT1/cmss/m/it/10.95\endcsname=127
```

in the preamble doesn't work; I get

```
! Missing font identifier.
<to be read again>
                   \OT1/cmss/m/it/10.95
```

I just played around a bit and used `\check@mathfonts` to initialize the fonts before the `\skewchar` command, but this seems like cheating to me. Moreover, this only initialized the sizes `6`, `8` and `10.95`.

My feeling is that the `\skewchar` command should be invoked at initialization time. Is this the correct approach, and yes, how do I implement that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OML}{cmss}{\skewchar\font127 }
```

should work. You can also put `\skewchar\font127` into the last parameter of the `\DeclareFontShape` macro.

```
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{cmss}{m}{it}{<-> cmss8t}{\skewchar\font127}
```