# xetex beamer math accent

Tags: beamer, xetex, accents

The math accent looks ugly if I compile my beamer slides with xelatex.

| [image: hat x in xetex] | [image: hat x in pdflatex] |
| --- | --- |
| `\hat x` in xelatex | `\hat x` in pdflatex |

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  $\hat x$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Uhm, interesting question, that was the old behaviour also for `pdftex` before Ariel Barton wrote the `sansmathaccents` package, which nowadays is loaded by default by `beamer`. (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4192/82917.) Apparently `xetex` doesn't understand that.

Comment: sansmathaccents only handle the cm-fonts, but xelatex and lualatex use lm. It would be good, if the package would be adapted to this situation. You can try `\AtBeginDocument
{\DeclareSymbolFont{pureletters}{OT1}{mathkerncmss}{m}{sl}
\SetSymbolFont{pureletters}{bold}{OT1}{mathkerncmss}{bx}{sl}}`, but if you use the bm package, perhaps more it needed.