# sansmathfonts makes regular text serif when compiling with XeLaTeX

Tags: beamer, xetex, sans-serif, sansmathfonts

I have the following document:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{}
        Test $ a\sigma $
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If I compile it with PDFLaTeX, I get the expected result:

[image]

However, with XeLaTeX I get the following strange result:

[image]

If I remove the line `\usepackage{sansmathfonts}` I get what you'd expect, both with PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX:

[image]

(note the "serif" σ).

I've tried explicitly telling `beamer` to use the sans font, but that didn't change anything. Also, the problem persists if I use `article` and set `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`, so I don't think this has anything to do with `beamer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages such as `sansmathfonts` are usually not designed with the font loading mechanisms of XeLaTeX in mind. While it might work generally, some unexpected problems are, well, expected, as you have found out.

In such situations using the normal approach for fonts in XeLaTeX generally works better, i.e., loading a system-installed font using `fontspec`.

For math specifically there is the `mathspec` package that works on top of `fontspec` and allows to specify the math font in some detail.

Of course you need to find a font that has all the required font shapes, i.e., latin, greek, italic, in sans-serif.

Example with Liberation Sans as font:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Liberation Sans}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Test of Liberation Sans}
        Test $ a\int_\infty \sqrt{\sigma\alpha\beta\pi} $
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really like the fonts provided by sansmathfonts. Am I right in assuming it wouldn't be feasible (or maybe legal?) convert those fonts to system fonts?

Comment: @saarl It is feasible, using FontForge for example, and it is also legal because the package is licensed under the [LPPL](https://ctan.org/license/lppl1.3c). But it would not be easy :) you could try contacting the package author to see if she can think of a solution. Something similar to the comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579971/xetex-beamer-math-accent#comment1459233_579971 may also do the trick (although I don't know which declaration would be needed here).