# arrows are broken with babel and lualatex

Tags: luatex, babel, hebrew

I am starting to lose my mind because of this weird bug that I don't understand how to solve. I do my homework with latex in Hebrew and I use `babel` to set it up. I have a custom package and class to define my style and commands. After fighting for hours to get it to compile without errors I found out that the `\Longrightarrow` is broken:
[image]

I tried to create a minimal example to reproduce the issue:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = he_HE
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{witharrows}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, provide=*]{babel}
\babelprovide[alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide{english}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz, ItalicFont=*-Regular, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3}]{Assistant}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}[Renderer=Harfbuzz, ItalicFont=*-Regular, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3}]{Assistant}
\babelfont[hebrew]{tt}[Renderer=Harfbuzz, ItalicFont=*-Regular, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3}]{Assistant}
\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\selectlanguage{hebrew}}

\begin{document}
דוגמה \textit{לחישוב}:
\begin{DispWithArrows*}
A &= (a + b)^2 \Arrow{נפתח את הסוגריים בביטוי} \\
&= a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{DispWithArrows*}
\underline{דוגמה} \textbf{נוספת}:
\begin{align*}
A &= (a + b)^2\\
&= a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{align*}

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
Some English example.
\end{otherlanguage}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, label=\alph*.]
    \item
בדיקה ראשונה.
    \item
בדיקה שנייה.
\end{enumerate}

\[ AB = I \Longrightarrow B = A^{-1} \]
\end{document}
```

but when compiling it, it worked as expected:
[image]

I went over the code trying to disable single features but couldn't find the source of this problem. The code that handles `babel` is identical to the code in the example above. Here are stripped versions of my files:

`my-style.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{my-style}[2023/03/06 My personal style and custom commands]

\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{tkz-base, tkz-euclide}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\RequirePackage{wrapfig}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{xifthen}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\RequirePackage{mathrsfs}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{moreenum}
\RequirePackage{bm}
\RequirePackage{upgreek}
\RequirePackage[euler]{textgreek}
\RequirePackage{import}
\RequirePackage{esint}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\RequirePackage[thicklines]{cancel}
\RequirePackage[per-mode=fraction, exponent-product=\cdot]{siunitx}
\RequirePackage[italicdiff]{physics}
\RequirePackage{nicefrac}
\RequirePackage{parskip}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{dsfont}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\RequirePackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage{ulem}
\RequirePackage{pgfkeys}
\RequirePackage{nicematrix}
\RequirePackage{witharrows}

% Hebrew option
\newboolean{hebrew}
\setboolean{hebrew}{false}

\DeclareOption{hebrew}{\setboolean{hebrew}{true}}
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{my-style}{Unknown '\CurrentOption'}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

% Font and lanuguage settings
\RequirePackage[bidi=basic, provide=*]{babel}
\babelprovide{english}
\babelprovide[alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz, ItalicFont=*-Regular, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3}]{Assistant}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}[Renderer=Harfbuzz, ItalicFont=*-Regular, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3}]{Assistant}
\babelfont[hebrew]{tt}[Renderer=Harfbuzz, ItalicFont=*-Regular, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3}]{Assistant}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{hebrew}}{
    \AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\selectlanguage{hebrew}}
}{
    \AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\selectlanguage{english}}
}

% witharrows options
\WithArrowsOptions{displaystyle}
\tikzset{
    WithArrows/arrow/.append style = {
        font= \small
    }
}

\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor=blue
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\OverSet}{ O{0cm} m m }{
    \overset{\raise #1 \hbox{\(#2\)}}{#3}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\UnderSet}{ O{0cm} m m }{
    \underset{\lower #1 \hbox{\(#2\)}}{#3}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\claptext}{ m }{\mathclap{\text{#1}}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Transpose}{ s m }{
    {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\pqty{#2}}{#2}}^{\mathrm{t}}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\InverseTranspose}{ s m }{
    {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\pqty{#2}}{#2}}^{-\mathrm{t}}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\HermitianTranspose}{ s m }{
    {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\pqty{#2}}{#2}}^{\dagger}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\InverseHermitianTranspose}{ s m }{
    {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\pqty{#2}}{#2}}^{-\dagger}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Conjugate}{ s m }{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\pqty{#2}}{#2}^{\ast}
}

% Physics commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\IdentityOperator}{}{\hat{I}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Change}{ m }{\mathop{\Delta#1}}
```

`homework.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{homework}[2022/11/01 My custom class for homework]

\LoadClass[a4paper, 12pt]{extarticle}

\RequirePackage{my-style}

\DeclareOption{hebrew}{\PassOptionsToPackage{hebrew}{my-style}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{extarticle}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\geometry{left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}

% HomeWork options
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\Course}{}{}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\StudentId}{}{#########}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\StudentEmail}{}{email@example.com}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\HWDate}{}{\today}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{hebrew}}{
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\Homework}{}{תרגיל בית}
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\StudentName}{}{שם הסטודנט}
}
{
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\Homework}{}{Homework assignment}
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\StudentName}{}{}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\SetCourse}{ m }{\RenewDocumentCommand{\Course}{}{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\SetHomework}{ m }{\RenewDocumentCommand{\Homework}{}{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\SetStudentName}{ m }{\RenewDocumentCommand{\StudentName}{}{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\SetStudentId}{ m }{\RenewDocumentCommand{\StudentId}{}{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\SetStudentEmail}{ m }{\RenewDocumentCommand{\StudentEmail}{}{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\SetHWDate}{ m }{\RenewDocumentCommand{\HWDate}{}{#1}}

% Styling customizations
\ifthenelse{\boolean{hebrew}}{
    % Customize title
    \titlelabel{חלק \thetitle}
}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Appendix}{ s }{
    \IfBooleanF{#1}{\newpage}
    \appendix
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{hebrew}}{
        \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

        % Customize title
        \titlelabel{נספח \thetitle\quad}
    }{}
}

% Homework functions
\newcounter{ProblemNum}
\newcounter{SubProblemNum}[ProblemNum]

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\TheProblemNum}{}{\arabic{ProblemNum}}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{hebrew}}{
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\TheSubProblemNum}{}{\alph{SubProblemNum}}
}{
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\TheSubProblemNum}{}{\arabic{SubProblemNum}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Section}{ m }{
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
    \section*{#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Problem}{ s o }{
    \IfBooleanF{#1}{\newpage}
    \stepcounter{ProblemNum}

    \phantomsection
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{hebrew}}{
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{שאלה \TheProblemNum \IfNoValueF{#2}{\; #2}}
        \subsection*{שאלה \TheProblemNum \IfNoValueF{#2}{\; #2}}
    }{
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Question \TheProblemNum \IfNoValueF{#2}{\; #2}}
        \subsection*{Question \TheProblemNum \IfNoValueF{#2}{\; #2}}
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Solution}{}{
    \phantomsection
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{hebrew}}{
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{פתרון}
        \subsubsection*{פתרון}
    }{
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Solution}
        \subsubsection*{Solution}
    }
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Part}{ o }{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
        \stepcounter{SubProblemNum}
        \phantomsection
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{hebrew}}{
            \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{סעיף \texorpdfstring{\TheSubProblemNum}{\arabic{SubProblemNum}}}
            \subsubsection*{סעיף \TheSubProblemNum}
        }{
            \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Part \texorpdfstring{\TheSubProblemNum}{\arabic{SubProblemNum}}}
            \subsubsection*{Part \TheSubProblemNum}
        }
    }{
        \phantomsection
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{hebrew}}{
            \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{סעיף #1}
            \subsubsection*{סעיף #1}
        }{
            \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Part #1}
            \subsubsection*{Part #1}
        }
    }
}

% Theorems and proofs
\ifthenelse{\boolean{hebrew}}{
    \newtheorem{lemma}{למה}[ProblemNum]
}{
    \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[ProblemNum]
}

% Lists
\newlist{QuestionParts}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[QuestionParts, 1]{align=left, leftmargin=*, label=\alph*.}
\setlist[QuestionParts, 2]{align=right, label=\arabic*.}

\newlist{SubParts}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[SubParts, 1]{align=left, labelsep=0pt, leftmargin=0pt, labelwidth=*, label=\uline{חלק \arabic*}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\nitem}{ o }{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
        \item\mbox{}\\
    }{
        \item[#1]\mbox{}\\
    }
}

% Hyperref and fancyhdr setup
\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={\StudentName},
    pdftitle={\Homework},
}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\;\empty}

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{hebrew}}{
    \lhead{שאלה \arabic{ProblemNum}}
}{
    \lhead{Question \arabic{ProblemNum}}
}
\chead{\Course}
\rhead{\Homework}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

`main.tex`:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = he_HE
\documentclass[hebrew]{homework}

\SetCourse{פיזיקה קוונטית 1}
\SetHomework{תרגיל בית 3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\import{./}{q1.tex}
\end{document}
```

`q1.tex`:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = he_HE
\Problem[צמוד הרמיטי]
\[
\HermitianTranspose*{\hat{O}^{-1}}\HermitianTranspose{\hat{O}} = \HermitianTranspose*{\hat{O}\hat{O}^{-1}} = \HermitianTranspose{\IdentityOperator} = \IdentityOperator
\Longrightarrow \tcbhighmath{\HermitianTranspose*{\hat{O}^{-1}} = \pqty{\HermitianTranspose{\hat{O}}}^{-1}}
\]
```

Compiling `main.tex` with `lualatex` produces the first picture. As I said before, I compared these files with the example above for hours, but couldn't find the source of this annoying bug. If someone could figure out what is happening here and how how to solve it, I'd really appreciate it.

P.S: I am using the font [Assistant](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Assistant).

Comment: debugging hebrew (bidi) problems is already hard enough, it gets impossible if you load tons of in part unsuitable packages. Remove your style file. Load only unicode-math and try with it. If you still have problems show a *short* example.

Comment: As workaround, move loading of `amsmath` (and all packages loading it) *after* the loading of `babel` adn the `\babelfont` commands. It should fix it.  Details in the answers...

Comment: hmm after painful dichotomy it appears you have to move these packages after the font set-up: `amsmath`, `amsfonts`, `amssymb`, `amsthm`, `mathtools`, `pgfplots`, `upgreek`, `tcolorbox` (the latter probably because of `[most]`, `moreenum`. (some I did not check really, at least moving all of them after the font set-up appears to work at my locale).

Comment: @user691586, It  would be much easier to load `unicode-math` before `fontspec`. It also fix the distortion when using `12pt` font size.

Comment: I should also point out that `unicode-math` internally loads `amsmath`, so you don't need to load both, and `fontspec` is `unicode-math` aware. Also `amssymb` loads `amsfonts` so you don't need to load the latter if you use the former.

Comment: @UdiFogiel I will edit my answer to add what I consider simplest work-around.  I do not disagree but loading `unicode-math` which is a very large dependency only to fix that would not be my preferred method...

Comment: @user691586 Indeed `unicode-math` is a bit hefty, but I think today it is better to work with .otf/.ttf fonts, but that can be subjective. Despite that, I think your workaround does not solve the distortion when using `12pt` as the default size. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4686/264024

Comment: @UdiFogiel Yes, my workaround only fixes the fontspec versus amsmath, it does not address the issue about the distortion at `12pt` which as the 2010 answer you give the link too explains finally boils down to core issues or features of the venerable Knuth fonts and definitely applies to pdflatex too, where using `unicode-math` is not an option! But for pdflatex we can use other math font, for example `txfonts` (or  `newtxmath`) and this fixes the issue there.  As per `lualatex/xelatex` one can also use for example `txfonts` (and then `no-math` for `fontspec`).  Only to say alternatives exist.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the glyph produced by `\Longrigtharrow` is not actually one glyph, but a composition of `⟹` (`\Rightarrow`) and `=` to lengthen its legs.  The problem is that the two glyphs comes from different fonts, and their composition is not deigned to be used without the default fonts.

Even with your "unsuccessful" minimal example, if you will look close enough you will see that actually the the legs of and the head does not overlap perfectly:

[image]

The reason for that is that your minimal example use `12pt` font size, and while the font `lmr12` exists (the default font used when  `fontspec` is loaded, which babel loads when the command `\babelfont` is used), the font `cmsy12` (where the head of the arrow is located) isn't, so LaTeX scales `cmsy10` but the result is not perfect.

Regarding your main document, in some cases fontspec will define the `mathrm` font as the documents main font, this is what causing the legs of your arrow to look disturbed, thay are actually the `=` from  the Assistant font.

To suppress that, either pass the `no-math` option to fontspec, you can do that by adding the line `\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}` before the first `\babelfont`, or you can rename your document class option, or you can laod the `unicode-math` package before `babel`. Probably the latter is preferable, as you are using `12pt` as the default font size.

The reason you don't not get a similar result with your minimal example is that by passing the `hebrew` option to the documentclass deceleration, you actually passing it to all the packages as well.

Since you essentially have `\RequirePackage[hebrew,bidi=basic, provide=*]{babel}` then `babel` is treating `hebrew` as the main language, and sets the main font to be the hebrew font.

You can produce similar result with much shorter document:

```
\documentclass[hebrew]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, provide=*]{babel}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{Assistant}

\begin{document}
\[\Longrightarrow\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide further explanation about the last part?
I don't understand why my custom `hebrew` option is passed to all packages. I want this option to quickly decide if I want a Hebrew or an English document, but I want to run the code for this explicitly as I have in my examples. I definitely don't want any options of my custom class to be passed implicitly to any package.

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer for adding workaround.

Aside from passing `no-math` option to `fontspec` (via `\PassOptionsToPackage`), or to make sure all packages loading `amsmath` are loaded after `fontspec` (which is a pain, for example `tcolorbox` with option "most" does it), the simplest to my mind is to

- add  `` \makeatletter\Umathcharnumdef\std@equal\Umathcodenum`\=\relax\makeatother `` immediately after `\begin{document}`.
- or add

  ```
    \makeatletter
    \AtBeginDocument{%
      \Umathcharnumdef\std@equal\Umathcodenum`\=\relax
    }%
    \makeatother
  ```

  anywhere in the preamble, if you are using LaTeX at least as recent as October 2020, or right before `\begin{document}` for older LaTeX.

You don't need to worry about `\std@minus` (which if you go reading the rest of this answer you will see mentioned) because `fontspec` (as far as I checked) does nothing special with the `-`.

---

This is only a complement to very good [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/683704/293669) by @UdiFogiel, as my comments were too long to fit as comments.

Compare the following situations:

1. A pdflatex document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{dejavu}

\begin{document}
a $\Longrightarrow$
\thispagestyle{empty}
\showoutput
\end{document}
% Local variables:
% TeX-engine: default
% End:
```

Then one has to considerably zoomed to confirm visually the slight mismatch
[image: longrightarrow with pdflatex]

and the log contains (don't worry about `)` it stands for a slot where is actually the arrow head)

```
....\OT1/DejaVuSerif-TLF/m/n/12 a
....\glue 3.81479 plus 1.9068 minus 1.27199
....\mathon
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 =
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x-1.99997
.....\kern -1.99997
....\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 )
....\mathoff
```

2. Now we try using luatex and fontspec something similar:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}

\begin{document}
a $\Longrightarrow$
\thispagestyle{empty}
\showoutput
\end{document}
% Local variables:
% TeX-engine: luatex
% End:
```

and it produces this where mismatch is obvious without zoom [image: lonrightarrow with fontspec]

The log contains:

```
....\TU/DejaVuSerif(0)/m/n/12 a
....\glue(\spaceskip) 3.81445 plus 1.90723 minus 1.27148
....\mathon
....\TU/DejaVuSerif(0)/m/n/12 =
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x-1.99997, direction TLT
.....\kern-1.99997 (italic)
....\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 )
....\mathoff
```

3. Same as 2. but without `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}

\begin{document}
a $\Longrightarrow$
\thispagestyle{empty}
\showoutput
\end{document}
% Local variables:
% TeX-engine: luatex
% End:
```

produces, and here I have to zoom a lot:
[image: lonrightarrow with luatex without amsmath]

and the log contains

```
....\TU/DejaVuSerif(0)/m/n/12 a
....\glue(\spaceskip) 3.81445 plus 1.90723 minus 1.27148
....\mathon
....\hbox(4.33081+0.0)x9.1388, direction TLT
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 =
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x-1.99997, direction TLT
.....\kern-1.99997 (italic)
....\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 )
....\mathoff
```

Note that in these log extracts the shown "font names" are actually the LaTeX "new font selection scheme (or system?) NFSS" assigned macro names.

So we see that the problem is not alone one of `fontspec`, but is a combination of `fontspec` and `amsmath` and a Unicode engine.

Now the `amsmath` definition of `\Longrightarrow` is

```
\renewcommand{\Longrightarrow}{%
  \DOTSB\protect\Relbar\protect\joinrel\Rightarrow}
```

and the definition of `\Relbar` is

```
\ams@DeclareRobustCommand\Relbar{\mathrel\std@equal}
```

and the definition of `\std@equal` is the slightly complex

```
\@ifundefined{Umathcode}
  {%
    \mathchardef\std@minus\mathcode`\-\relax
    \mathchardef\std@equal\mathcode`\=\relax
  }
  {%
   \Umathcharnumdef\std@minus\Umathcodenum`\-\relax
   \Umathcharnumdef\std@equal\Umathcodenum`\=\relax
  }
\@ifundefined{Umathcode}
  {%
    \AtBeginDocument{%
      \mathchardef\std@minus\mathcode`\-\relax
      \mathchardef\std@equal\mathcode`\=\relax
      }%
  }
  {%
    \AtBeginDocument{%
      \Umathcharnumdef\std@minus\Umathcodenum`\-\relax
      \Umathcharnumdef\std@equal\Umathcodenum`\=\relax
    }%
  }
```

which says that `\std@equal` is an alias to the `=` in math mode and `amsmath` insists upon it as it redoes the definition at begin document.

Without amsmath we have similar things leading to `\Relbar` except that the latter definition is to be a robust macro which expands to `\mathrel{=}`.  So basically it looks the same as the above stuff.

So why the difference?  In the example with `amsmath` let's do

```
\makeatletter
a $\std@equal = \Longrightarrow$
```

then the output is
[image: std@equal and equal differ]. Hence amsmath went out of its way to make `\std@equal` and `=` the same but in the end they are not.  Without amsmath the arrow will use `\Relbar` which will use `\mathrel{=}` and there is no mismatch.

But here what happens is that `\std@equal` got frozen to the mathcode of the equal sign, which maps to using a given slot in the "operators" TeX font "family" for math mode.  With `fontspec` this "operators" is modified to match the roman font of the document.  At the same time `fontspec` does modify the `=` in math mode to *not* use the `=` from the text font.  But it does not modify the amsmath `\std@equal` which will thus end up using the document "roman" font.

The modification by `fontspec` of "operators" in file `fontspec-luatex.sty`:

```
  \DeclareSymbolFont{operators}\g_fontspec_encoding_tl\g__fontspec_mathrm_tl\mddefault\shapedefault
```

This modification by `fontspec` of `=`:

```
  \DeclareSymbolFont{legacymaths}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
...
     \DeclareMathSymbol{=}{\mathrel}{legacymaths}{61}
```

Then we can check the mathcode of `=` as well as the math versions

```
> \symlegacymaths=\char"4.
l.8 \show\symlegacymaths
                      
? 
> 73400381.
l.9 \showthe\mathcode`=
                     
? 
> \temp=\Umathchar"3"04"00003D.
l.11 \show\temp
             
? 
> \std@equal=\Umathchar"3"00"00003D.
l.12 \show\std@equal
                  
?
```

I used for this

```
\makeatletter
\show\symlegacymaths
\showthe\mathcode`=
\Umathcharnumdef\temp\Umathcodenum`=\relax
\show\temp
\show\std@equal
```

to disentangle the "Umathcode" of `=` via an alias `\temp` which allows to confirm that `=` is now taken from "legacymaths" (number 4) whereas `\std@equal` still refers to the glyph from "operators" (number 0).  But "operators" now maps to document "roman" font (which in the case of OP using `\babelfont` will actually be the font for Hebrew).

Conclusion: one of `fontspec` or `amsmath` has to take into account the other's existence.  Probably this is an already known bug reported on the `fontspec` [issue tracker](https://github.com/latex3/fontspec/issues) but I found only one issue mentioning `amsmath` and it is closed and unrelated.