Issue with Broken Long Arrows (`\Longrightarrow`) at Font Sizes Above 11pt in pdflatex
When using in math mode long arrows like \Longrightarrow, \Longleftarrow, etc., I encounter an issue with the arrows being broken when I use a font size larger than 11pt. With 11pt, everything works fine:
\documentclass[11pt,border={0pt 1pt 0pt 2pt}]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\Longrightarrow$
\end{document}


However, with 12pt, the arrow appears broken, and the two symbols $=$ and $\rightarrow$ are misaligned and do not overlap properly, resulting in an unattractive rendering:
\documentclass[12pt,border={0pt 1pt 0pt 2pt}]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\Longrightarrow$
\end{document}


Interestingly, this problem does not occur when using the mathabx package, but unfortunately, it is incompatible with amssymb and other packages that depend on it:
\documentclass[12pt,border={0pt 1pt 0pt 2pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$\Longrightarrow$
\end{document}


The arrow displays correctly when using unicode-math, but I need to use pdflatex, which does not support it:
\documentclass[12pt,border={0pt 1pt 0pt 2pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\Longrightarrow$
\end{document}


Any suggestions on how to fix this issue while sticking to pdflatex?

The problem here is essentially that the = comes from cmr and LaTEx uses cmr12 at 12pt, but the => arrow comes from cmsy which is not availaable at 12pt design size so uses cmsy10 at 12pt.  This different scaling mechanism can cause artiacts at some sizes.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/683686/1090  and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4684/longrightarrow-doesnt-look-good-in-12pt/4686#4686
