# Lowering an accented character

Tags: xetex

In the given MWE, the new `sd` command produces ^ carets higher than the `hat` carets. Is there a way to adjusted the `newcommand` at the bottom of the preamble to lower these carets to match? (Alegreya can be downloaded for free from [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/alegreya).)

It might seem silly, but I'm really going after the look of the `\newcommand` carets more than the `hat` carets.

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont[
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = Alegreya-Regular,
    ItalicFont = Alegreya-Italic,
    BoldFont = Alegreya-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont = Alegreya-BoldItalic,
    UprightFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = AlegreyaSC-Regular},
    ItalicFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = AlegreyaSC-Italic},
    BoldFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = AlegreyaSC-Bold},
    BoldItalicFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = AlegreyaSC-BoldItalic},
    Ligatures = TeX]
    {Alegreya}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)
    [Numbers=OldStyle]{Alegreya}
\newcommand{\sd}[1]{\accent"02C6 #1}

\begin{document}

\sd{1} $\hat{1}$ \sd{2} $\hat{2}$ \sd{3} $\hat{3}$ \sd{4} $\hat{4}$ \sd{5} $\hat{5}$ \sd{6} $\hat{6}$ \sd{7} $\hat{7}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Oddly, the `sd` carets were exactly what I wanted when the following was the `fontspec`:

```
\setmainfont[
  SmallCapsFont={Alegreya SC},
  ItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-Italic},
  BoldFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-Bold},
  BoldItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-BoldItalic},
  Ligatures=TeX,
]{Alegreya}
```

For ligature and international character reasons, I had to clarify the `fontspec` as you saw in the original MWE; can anyone explain why that might be?

The answer may be in [How do I lower the \widetilde accent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/how-do-i-lower-the-widetilde-accent-i-e-move-it-closer-to-the-variable), but to be honest I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: I would not use oldstyle numerals in math formulas; stick with lining-style numerals for formulas.

Comment: I agree with you, but this is a humanities dissertation, and thus no math formulas :-)

Comment: So why define a maths font? And some humanities work includes maths.

Comment: I defined a math font in the MWE to show where I would like the carets to be.

Comment: What are these accented numbers for exactly, if they are not maths or similar?

Comment: In music, the caret above a number indicates a scale degree; so in C Major, C is ^1, G is ^5, etc.

Comment: I can't even compile it. XeTeX can't find the fonts even though they are installed. (XeTeX's ability to find fonts on my machine, at least, varies between minimal and nil.)

Comment: This is one of the reasons my `fontspec` is so specific; there are ligature problems on this system that other folks don't seem to have.

Comment: Is LuaLaTeX an option? If I ditch the `mathspec` stuff, it seems to place the accents more-or-less where you want them. (I can't compare exactly as I lose the comparison but they are certainly closer to the hats.) LuaTeX almost always works better for me than XeTeX - it is just so much less temperamental (in general).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix the height of the character by using `\halign` instead of `\accent`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont[
    Extension = .ttf, % I only have TrueType
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
    UprightFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = *SC-Regular},
    ItalicFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = *SC-Italic},
    BoldFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = *SC-Bold},
    BoldItalicFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = *SC-BoldItalic},
    Ligatures = TeX
]{Alegreya}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[
  Numbers=OldStyle
]{Alegreya-Regular}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sd}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      ##\cr
      \hidewidth\char"02C6 \hidewidth\cr
      \noalign{\kern-0.95ex}
      #1\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\sd{1} $\hat{1}$ \sd{2} $\hat{2}$ \sd{3} $\hat{3}$ 
\sd{4} $\hat{4}$ \sd{5} $\hat{5}$ \sd{6} $\hat{6}$ 
\sd{7} $\hat{7}$ \sd{8} $\hat{8}$ \sd{9} $\hat{9}$
\sd{0} $\hat{0}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You've helped me out several times in the past, and you came through again. I had to adjust to `\kern-2ex`, but it's perfect!